# Checking bookmarks in pdfs in a mass quantity in Adobe Acrobat Pro

Tags: bookmarks, adobe-acrobat, pdf-reader

Say if I have 100 pdf's and I want to quickly check to see if they are all bookmarked without opening them individually, is there a tool to go about this efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check which PDFs have bookmarks and which ones don't, I would recommend [PDFtk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit). Just install it and at the (Windows) command prompt switch to the dir with the PDFs and enter the following command:

```
for %a in (*.pdf) do @pdftk "%~a" dump_data | find /i "bookmark" >NUL && echo Yes - "%~a" || echo No  - "%~a"
```

You'll see output similar to the following:

```
Yes - "a b.pdf"
No  - "c d.pdf"
...
```